Values Are of Wrong Data Type in Formula in VBA Excel
I'm trying to multiply a variant array of coefficients by an independent variable stored in an excel sheet through a function in VBA to return the dependent value. The array has one integer in the beginning and the rest are doubles. The value in the cell is driven off of a formula and is a number, but when I try and input the array and the cell value into the function, it keeps saying something is the wrong data type.
Public eqCoefs As Variant

Function totalOffset(PA As Double) As Double
    
    'Declare calculation variables
    Dim degree As Integer
    Dim axialSB As Double
    Dim offset As Double
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    'Set count variables
    degree = CInt(eqCoefs(0))
    counter = 1
    
    'Match coefficients from regression graph to radial spring back and pitch angle with correct exponents
    For n = 1 To degree
        For i = 0 To n
            axialSB = axialSB + eqCoefs(counter) * (PA ^ (n - i))
            counter = counter + 1
        Next i
    Next n
    totalOffset = axialSB
End Function 

This is what is in the eqCoefs array, defined in another function: [4, -45.7635, -10423.7192, 0.0916, 125.3645, 13474.074, 0.0008, -0.19, -114.23, -7696.3461, 0.0, -0.0013, 0.105, 34.5752, 1638.0121, 3009.2862]
The number in the cell is 13.74, driven by the formula =DEGREES(ATAN((N25)/(PI()*coiling!$R$25)))
Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried putting CDbl in front of both numbers. I've tried taking in PA as a Range and getting the value. I've tried setting eqCoefs into a variable with a double data type and then multiplying. I've tried getting totalOffset to return a Variant instead of a double, nothing has worked.
Sub equationExport()
'Declare variables
Dim equationCoefficients As Variant
Dim coefficientHolder As String
Dim db As New DatabaseReg
'Read in equation coefficients and degree of regression
coefficientHolder = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RegressionGraph").Range("J4").Value
degree = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RegressionGraph").Range("L2").Value

'Get equation coefficients as a string from cell J4 and split it into array
equationCoefficients = Split(coefficientHolder, ", ")
'Set first array value as degree
equationCoefficients(0) = degree

' Converts array to doubles
For i = 0 To UBound(equationCoefficients)
    equationCoefficients(i) = CDbl(equationCoefficients(i))
Next i
db.Initialize "...\targetDataSheet.xlsx"

Dim targetSheetCoil As Worksheet
Set targetSheetCoil = 
db.targetDatabase.Worksheets("RegressionEquationData")

' Insert new record into the database
db.InsertRecord holderArray, targetSheetCoil

' Close the database connection
db.Terminate
End Sub

This is how I'm taking in the array of doubles from a workbook and writing it to a sheet using the DatabaseReg class that I wrote, then I'm reading that array of doubles into another workbook and setting it equal to eqCoefs.

Working fine for me when called from a worksheet cell using =totalOffset(13.74) or when pointing the formula at a cell with the equivalent of =DEGREES(ATAN((N25)/(PI()*coiling!$R$25)))

I'll try running it with eqCoefs defined within the function, it might be because I converted a string to a variant array and the data values are messed up. I checked that the values were all the right type and value though.

At least until you sort out all possible scenarios, I recommend accepting a variant as the parameter type and return a variant, as well; you can check for the type in VBA and do different things. Once you find all these scenarios and write handlers for each; you can change to double/double
